# What is the SwiftUI equivalent of clipsToBounds?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I have a scrollview in SwiftUI for which I dont want to clip the contents which are out of bounds while scrolling. In UIKit, we can achieve this by setting `clipsToBounds` to `false` for the scrollview. How would you do the same in SwiftUI. Or what's the best practice to achieve a similar behavior in SwiftUI?

Btw I know we can use `UIViewRepresentable` to map UIKit view or if we use some libraries like [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) we can get the underlying UIKit scrollview and set `clipsToBounds` to false. But I'd like to know if there is a native SwiftUI way to do it.

This is some code which could make the question a bit more clear.

```swift
struct MyScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            header
            content
        }
    }
    
    var header: some View {
        Text("Header")
            .padding()
            .frame(minHeight: 200)
    }
    
    var content: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.orange)
    }
}
```

This is what it renders, scrollview content is clipped as I scroll up.

[image]

What I'm looking for is like this, I should be able to see content under the header as I scroll up.

[image]

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: ```.clipped()```?

Comment: @udi that would set it to true. I'm looking for something which would set `clipsToBounds` to false

Comment: By default there is no clipping unless specified. Can you give an example ?

Comment: @PtitXav I'm using a `ScrollView` and by default its clipped. I have a view on top of scroll view (like a header view), which is partially transparent and I need to see the contents of the scrollview under the header view as I scroll.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT : Use a Stack and add an empty header to the scroll view:

```
struct MyScrollView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            content
            VStack {
                header
                Spacer()
            }
        }
    }
    
    var header: some View {
        Text("Header")
            .padding()
            .frame(minHeight: 200)
    }
    
    var content: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Spacer()
                .frame(height:200)
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
            Text("Content").padding()
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.orange)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately it won't work. LazyVStack updates the frame in a weird way which is not what I'm looking for. I've updated the code in the question to better show what I want.

Comment: I think in your case you should use a ZStack and am empty view at the begin of scrollview

Comment: Adding a spacer on top and putting everything in an ZStack will work in this case. Even you can use a geometry reader to adjust the height of the header if the header grows dynamically based on content. But this feels so hacky and not exactly what I'm looking for. A modifier similar to `clipped()` which can do the opposite of it would be ideal.

Comment: From what I understand, the problem is that in SwiftUI, all view are Rectangles and do not extend beyond affected borders. Only lazy views seems to have the ability to draw outside frame. That what I understood, but I may be wrong.